# Qt Multi language QCombobox

Tags: qt, qcombobox, multilingual

I have got a problem with multi language qt (change language on the fly). My form have a combobox which should be translated when language changed. When languageChanged, the app call method retranslateUi() to translate item in the combobox. The combobox have slot corresponding for signal currentIndexChanged().

```
void on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
//do something
}
```

But when method retranslateUi() called, I do this:

```
void retranslateUi()
{
ui->comboBox->clear();
ui->comboBox->insertItems(0, QStringList()
         << QApplication::translate("SettingDialog", "English", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8)
         << QApplication::translate("SettingDialog", "French", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8)
        );
}
```

Problem is: each statement in retranslateUi() will emit the signal currentIndexChanged(), then the slot will call again.

How can I avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clear()` and `insertItems()` will trigger the `currentIndexchanged(int)`  SLOT function of combobox as former changes the index to -1 and later will also changes the index as you are inserting items at position 0.

So restrict `on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int)` by using a flag as follows...

```
void on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
if(!retranslateFlag)
//do something
}


void retranslateUi()
{
retranslateFlag = true;
ui->comboBox->clear();
ui->comboBox->insertItems(0, QStringList()
     << QApplication::translate("SettingDialog", "English", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8)
     << QApplication::translate("SettingDialog", "French", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8)
    );
retranslateFlag = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to temporary block signals for an object:

```
void retranslateUi()
{
    auto isBlocked = ui->comboBox->blockSignals(true);
    ui->comboBox->clear();
    ui->comboBox->insertItems(0, QStringList()
     << QApplication::translate("SettingDialog", "English", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8)
     << QApplication::translate("SettingDialog", "French", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8);
    );
    ui->comboBox->blockSignals(isBlocked);
}
```

Or since Qt 5.3 use exception safe RAII QSignalBlocker

```
QSignalBlocker blocker(ui->comboBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clearing the `comboBox` you can only change the text of an item via `void QComboBox::setItemText(int index, const QString &text)`

```
void retranslateUi()
{
    ui->comboBox->setItemText(0, QApplication::translate("SettingDialog", "English", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
    ui->comboBox->setItemText(1, QApplication::translate("SettingDialog", "French", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
}
```

I assume your solution and the answer from ScarCode will lose the current selected item in the comboBox. This solution should not lose it. (Not tested)